# Open source VideoPlayer / AudioPlayer / MediaPlayer GUI / UI resource available?

Tags: android, user-interface, open-source, resources, media-player

I'm looking for a user interface for a MediaPlayer which should be able to play video as well as audio files.
Furthermore it needs the following things (nothing fancy):

- TextView for playing time
- Progress Bar for progress visulization
- Play/Pause/Stop buttons
- **NO** playlist functionality required, the player will *only* play a single item (that's why I don't need next/previous buttons).

It sounds pretty much like the standard audio-player of Android >= 2.0. Sure, I could try to find its source code but that would require to tediously check out the entire source. I'm just asking for a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance,
steff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I'm a real moron. Since the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) don't call `mVideoView.start();`I thought I doesn't work. So the answer to my silly question is [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html), which lets you play videos as well as audio files. For controlling those files just add a [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html), call `mediaController.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);` and you're good to go. Simple as that...